# Multiple IFS FUNCTION in Google Sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, match, multiple-conditions, ifs

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b68vC.png)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Asd_7njduyx4ku9ZzqqBLmbLxXuZ2RBNlZvCQx12bFk/edit?usp=sharing

Referring to above sample data pictures & link, I need help make formula in Column E where the condition are as below :

1. IF Column A = SAMPLE/DRAWING UPDATES, AND Column C = COMPLETED, search data in column B based on data in Column D, if found matches return as "Existing Data". If not found, "Updates required"
2. IF Column A = SAMPLE/DRAWING UPDATES, AND Column C = IN PROGRESS/NOT YET STARTED, return as "Pending confirmation".
3. IF Column A = SAMPLE/DRAWING UPDATES, AND Column C = CANCELLED/ON HOLD, return as "No action required".

I've tried below formula for No. 1, but seems like not works. I am new help. Please help.
=IFS(AND(OR(A2:2="SAMPLE",A2:A="DRAWING UPDATES"),C2:C="COMPLETED"),INDEX(IF(LEN(B2:2), IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B, D2:D, 0)), "Existing Data", "Updates required"),)))

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are mixing comparing a whole range at a time versus a specific row at a time.

I'll offer two solutions that cover all the scenarios you've asked for.

## Single Cell

```
=IF(OR(A2="SAMPLE",A2="DRAWING UPDATES"),
IFS(C2="COMPLETED",IF(IFNA(XMATCH(B2,D$2:D,0),FALSE),"Existing Data","Updates Required"),
OR(C2="IN PROGRESS",C2="NOT YET STARTED"),"Pending Confirmation",
OR(C2="CANCELLED",C2="ON HOLD"),"No action required"),
"")
```

You need to put this in the first cell in Column E, then use the fill handle and drag it down to the remaining cells.

## Full Range

Alternatively, if you just want to put it in the column and have it apply without having to drag it down to every cell, then use the formula:

```
=LET(existing,D2:D,MAP(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(task,part,status,IF(OR(task="SAMPLE",task="DRAWING UPDATES"),
IFS(status="COMPLETED",IF(IFNA(XMATCH(part,existing,0),FALSE),"Existing Data","Updates Required"),
OR(status="IN PROGRESS",status="NOT YET STARTED"),"Pending Confirmation",
OR(status="CANCELLED",status="ON HOLD"),"No action required"),
""))))
```

- `A2:A` is the *Task* Column.
- `B2:B` is the *Part No* Column.
- `C2:C` is the *Status* Column.
- `D2:D` is the *Existing* Column.